# sample code for create dynamic sql server table

Tags: sql-server

I trying to build a site that is works with electronic currencies. Example, a WebMoney currency has its own set of parameters, such as wmid etc. And uKash has its own parameters also a series of other parameters, such as emails etc. Now it is not clear how many currency  site administrators is introduced while the unknown parameters I thought to myself, bank currency should be constructed in a dynamic table that the user can set the parameters. Know i don't how to implement it?

Comment: here you want to create a table with dynamic number of columns in it?

Answer (score 1):

Tables can't have dynamic columns

You can add a table for each form of web currency that contains the parameters those currencies require = ie: A WebMoney table, a uKash table, etc.

Or you can add an XML column to your main table that contains the variable data information for the specific web currency in question. 
eg:

```
<webcurrency type="webmoney">
    <wmid>1</wmid>
<webmoney>
```

and

```
<webcurrency type="uKash">
    <email>bob@ukash.com</email>
<webmoney>
```

Given your intention to allow for future currencies, perhaps the second choice is preferable.